# NLP - Find keyword from the sentence

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, nltk

I'm working on NLP project, from the below attached code. 
I could only match and find similarity score for the words given in the list.

Can anyone help me how to find the similarity from paragraph?
Lets assume List A contains a paragraph & list B contains a keyword.
How to find the keyword in List A?

```
from collections import Counter
from math import sqrt
import eng_to_ipa as ipa

def word2vec(word):
    cw = Counter(word)
    sw = set(cw)
    lw = sqrt(sum(c*c for c in cw.values()))
    return cw, sw, lw

def cosdis(v1, v2):
    common = v1[1].intersection(v2[1])
    return sum(v1[0][ch]*v2[0][ch] for ch in common)/v1[2]/v2[2]

list_A = ['e-commerce', 'ecomme', 'e-commercy', 'ecomacy', 'E-Commerce', 'E Commerce']

list_B = ['E-Commerce']

IPA_list_a = []
IPA_list_b = []
for each in list_A:
    IPA_list_a.append(ipa.convert(each))
for each in list_B:
    IPA_list_b.append(ipa.convert(each))

for word in IPA_list_a:
    for key in IPA_list_b:
            res = cosdis(word2vec(word), word2vec(key))
            print(res)
```

Comment: Can you explain what change do you want in the code? Do you want an optimisation? Because as it appears you already have the code to calculate distance between lists.

Comment: Assume that List B is a keyword and List A contains a paragraph. 
I want to find the words in paragraph which are similar to keyword and calculate the score.

Comment: So you want to compare a single token to a list of tokens? What relation do you expect between the list and the single token? you could just calculate the average similarity between each list member and the singleton, but this may miss your intention. Could you tell us more about your application field?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NLP - Find Similar/Phonetic word and calculate score in a paragraph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60427951/nlp-find-similar-phonetic-word-and-calculate-score-in-a-paragraph)